# Script runs in Unix but not in Informatica command task

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My script ran successfully in Unix but not in a command task of an Informatica workflow. The permissions are fine, and the parameter file and variables have been declared in the workflow. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the machine you are running informatica on, is running in a unix box.
If it is on a windows machine, you will have to run the DOS equivalent command for your script.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether informatica repository is pointing to same **UNIX server**, in which the script to executed from informatica is present.

Answer (score 0):

I to faced same situation ,please check the propertied of script file make it as 755(CHMOD),It should work.

Regards
Rama

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permission issue. If you are executing a shell command from Informatica, right click the file in SFTP and click on "Properties" (I am using Winscp).Give full permission to the file and now it should work.

[image]